# How to avoid multiple db calls for inserting an object with related entities in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

I have a table say Transactions that has two foreign keys. One foreign key references Customers Table and the other to BillAmount Table. So my POCO is like

```
public class Transaction
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string BillAmountId { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class BillAmount
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public double Amount {get;set;}
}
```

When I try to insert a new `Transaction` object, I notice that there in total 3 calls made to the database:

1. To fetch `Customer` record corresponding to the id present in the `Transaction` object
2. To fetch `BillAmount` record corresponding to the id present in the `Transaction` object
3. `INSERT` command which finally inserts a new `Transaction` object

How do I prevent calls 1) and 2) ?

Comment: Are those your actual Models? Doesn't seem like it. Also, how do you intend to get the Customer and BillAmount without querying?

Comment: these are not my actual models, but very close to what i have. But why do i need to query Customer,BillAmount?

Comment: With the information you provided is very difficult if at all possible to help you. At least include the relevant parts where you query and insert the records.

Comment: If your DB model have a relationkey you can associate with your id itself rather than fetching the customer itself. `Transaction.BillAmountId = 5;` this will associate the object with the transaction so you can avoid fetching

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you use ORM tool (like EF core), you should reorganize your entities according to it like;

```
public class Transaction {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public BillAmount BillAmount { get; set; }
}

public class Customer {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BillAmount {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

When you call as shown below, it completes your work in one transaction (one insert).

```
public void InsertTransaction() {
        //Some dummy data
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.Id = "5";
        customer.Name = "George";

        BillAmount billAmount = new BillAmount();
        billAmount.Id = "7";
        billAmount.Amount = 2.0;

        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
        transaction.Id = "1";
        transaction.Customer = customer;
        transaction.BillAmount = billAmount;

        //Complete in one insert
        context.Transaction.Add(transaction);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Interesting why is that so?

Comment: It is obvious that your Transaction model has **join** relation with your Customer and BillAmount models. So you should reorganize your model according to this as i shown above. Having **owned entity** in code side means that you **join** that entity by its root entity in db side @jayasurya_j

Comment: when i execute the above program i get error the saying 'can't insert duplicate customer id 5', i thought EF will be intelligent enough to avoid INSERT when id is already present. What is wrong here

Comment: Yes, you are right. These are just dummy data. I think your customer id is primary key so it needs to be unique. And you already have a customer with its id is 5 in database. You can try this with other data which does not exist in database. @jayasurya_j

Comment: As addition, if you have your primary key as **auto_increment** in database, you should not fill id property, just set name property.  @jayasurya_j

Comment: No, my use case is to insert a new transaction where customer id is already present. But if i do it the way you mentioned it says duplicate id, as i understand EF is trying to create a new customer which i don't want. how do i avoid this? should i fetch customer and set it to tracking so that ef knows the customer is already present? I know that will work but that means i am making 2 db calls.

Comment: According to the models i have shown above (not accroding to your models), Customer has join with your Transaction model, and if it is already present, that means it is already joined with a Transaction. If we keep going according to your models there are no join between your tables (at the code side). So first you should decide to change your models as i shown above and it is not possible to face a Customer record that is already in db unless your data is meaningless.